# How To Implement Social Login With Django?

Tags: python-3.6, google-oauth, google-openid, django-socialauth, django-1.11

I have a website where users can log in with `username` and `password`,  now I want to implement google login. so, i am planning to use `social-auth-app-django`, and I want to use `sub` field return by google as username, but the problem is when the user login using google, I want to update old users username also, so what is the best way to achieve this?

for example:
     let's say the user john has username: John and email is `john@domain.com`, now if he login using his google account I want to update his username as `sub` field like `1076915035xxxxxxxxxx`

Problem:
       Since the website is for an organization, there are chances for same Gmail(GSuite) account for users with the different time period. like if John leaves an organization another user whose name is John can get the new Gmail account with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by adding custom pipelines like

```
"""
return the username
"""
def get_username(strategy, details, response, backend, user=None, *args, 
**kwargs):
    sub = response.get("id")
    return { "username" : sub }
```

The above method which return `sub` field as username

```
"""
associate users by username and sub field return by google
"""
def associate_by_email_sub(backend, details, response, user=None, *args, 
**kwargs):
email = details.get("email")
username = response.get("id")

if user:
    return None

if email and username:
    users = list(User.objects.filter(email=email, username=username))
    if len(users) == 0:
        #return {  'user' : None, 'is_new' : True }
        return None
    elif len(users) > 1:
        raise AuthException(
            backend,
            'The given email address is associated with another account'
        )
    else:
        return { 'user' : users[0], 'is_new' : False }
```

the above method will check the `email` and `username` field for the old user,

and added those methods in the pipeline.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
#pipeline which fetch all information required from user and returned in simple format
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
# Get the social uid from whichever service we're authing thru. The uid is
# the unique identifier of the given user in the provider.
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
#verify the current auth process such us whitelist domain names on email
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
# Checks if the current social-account is already associated in the site.
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
#Make up a username for this person, appends a random string on collision
'apps.user.social.get_username',
#Associate By Email And Sub 
'apps.user.social.associate_by_email_sub',
#CREATE USER
'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
# Create the record that associates the social account with the user.
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
# Populate the extra_data field in the social record with the values
# specified by settings (and the default ones like access_token, etc).
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
# Update the user record with any changed info from the auth service.
'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
  )
```

To set `sub` field as `uid` in `social_auth_usersocialauth` table set the option below in settings.py

> SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USE_UNIQUE_USER_ID = True